# Using Regex in Ruby to parse out a chunk of file names

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to standardize file names in a directory that have some similarities, but are not always consistent.  They are, however, standard enough.

Examples of file names (where the date is Month/Day/Year):

- Weekly sales report 022213 LV.xls
- Weekly sales report 091908 LV-F.xls
- Weekly sales 072508.xls
- Weekly U S sales V1.0 061308.xls
- Weekly U.S. Sales Jan0606.xls

My current solution has been an effective, but ugly find and replace for any possible string combinations.  x.gsub!(/^Weekly|sales|report|U S|U.S.|\s/,'')

However, I would assume that there would be a way to look at the file name string and grab the chunk that has all of the date information.  This would be the chunk bounded by whitespace on the left and ends in at least 4 digits.  Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement as stated would suggest the following:

```
date_portion = x.match(/\s(\S*\d{4,8})/)[1]
```

That's: match one whitespace char, then capture zero-or-more non-whitespace, followed by 4 to 8 digits; return the captured text.

Comment: Looks good, you can check with http://rubular.com/ just post your test strings in (file names) and the regex above

Comment: You're welcome. Remember you can mark this answer as "Correct" by clicking the green tick mark (as well as "helpful" by clicking the up arrow).